# Set Excel Column number Format as a text on laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm working with Maatwebsite\Excel.
But There is an problem, when i export excel some column converted to number format.
[for example[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbVJR.png)

How can I solve it?
I already set a column as a text.

```
public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [
        'G' =>NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
         
    ];
}
```

But it is not working. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to set format to `@`

`` 'G' => `@`, ``

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes I did it. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the PhpSpreadsheet's default value binder behavior by implementing the `WithCustomValueBinder` concern and the `bindValue` method.

```
public function bindValue(Cell $cell, $value)
{
    $cell->setValueExplicit($value, DataType::TYPE_STRING2);
    return true;
}
```

Note that this will convert all cells into text. If you want conditional formatting then you can refer [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#value-binders)

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution, add a space at the end of a integer

```
public function map($data) : array {
        return [
            $data->UPC ." ",
        ];
}
```